# Using jekyll's "includes" with remark

Tags: markdown, jekyll, static-site, remarkjs, static-site-generation

I'm happily using remark with jekyll. Jekyll let's me work with a template file, as it is descrbed in the [wiki](https://github.com/gnab/remark/wiki/Using-with-Jekyll).

I would also like to use jekyll's `include` command in my slides, e.g. `{% include something.html %}`. But somehow, I cant get this working: when I build my slides, the command `{% include something.html %}` is parsed *literally* into my slide (see screenshot below).

The content of my `default-presentation.md` file is below, where as `_includes/test.html` contains just `<p>test</p>`. I've also created a minimal repo containing all the files, [here](https://github.com/ratnanil/remark-jekyll/).

Full disclosure: I also asked this question via a [github issue](https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/660)

```
---
layout: presentation
title: Default Presentation
permalink: /default-presentation/
---

# My Awesome Presentation

{% include test.html %}
```

[image: Screenshot 2021-09-25 at 23-59-13 Default Presentation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `_layouts/presentation.html` file, you are calling `{{ page.content }}`. The `page.` part of that is calling the content from that page as-is. If you want Jekyll to parse content you should use `{{ content }}`.

Comment: oh man, I would not have found that! The trouble is, if I omit the `page.`, jekyll does crazy things with my remark markup. is there a way to use first inject the includes into my `default-presentation.md`, and then still use `page.content`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with remark so I'm not sure what "crazy things" you're seeing, but maybe try creating a second layout. Pass `default-presentation.md` to the `presentation.html` layout using `{{ content }}`. Then pass that to a new layout, `default.html` perhaps, using the `{{ page.content }}` ...or maybe the reverse of that.

Comment: Good idea! I've tried several things, haven't been successful yet. Will comment an update if i find a solution.